# Monacaのinputタグからカメラを起動したい

Tags: monaca, html5

カメラを呼び出して撮影した写真orギャラリから選択した写真をアップロードするツールを作っています。
スマホにインストールして動作確認中ですがandroidでの挙動が思ったようにいきません。

iPhoneの場合、ボタンをタップすると「写真またはビデオを取る」「フォトライブラリ」「その他」「キャンセル」が表示されます。
androidの場合「次から開く」というメニューが出て、「ドライブ」や「ギャラリー」はあるのですがカメラで撮影できそうなアイテムはありません。
また、写真を長押ししても複数選択できない状態です。

プラグインはCameraとCaptureを有効にしています。
HTML内で下記のように書いています。

```
    input type="file" id="img" accept="image/*;capture=camera" multiple="multiple">
```

iPhoneと同じような挙動にするには、何か他の記述が必要でしょうか？

---追記---
アプリのパーミッションはAndroidManifest.xmlに
＜uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />を追記して、
端末のアプリ情報で「写真と動画の撮影」が付いているのは確認しています。
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=ja

Answer (score 1):

Monacaで使用しているCordovaのソースコード(Androidのネイティブコード)を確認してみたのですが、Input[Type="FILE"]で呼ばれるメソッド(SystemWebChromeClient.javaのopenFileChooserやonShowFileChooser)で指定されているIntentが

```
android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT
```

として実装されているため、カメラの起動は出来ないようです。（カメラを使いたい時は、`android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE`というインテントを使う)

そのため、カメラを起動させたい場合は、カメラプラグインを利用した方が良いと思います。
その場合、カメラプラグインで取得した画像を、そのままinput type="file"に紐づけることは出来ないので、用途に応じて以下のように対応すると良いのではないでしょうか。
1. サーバーに送信するのであればFileTransferプラグインを使用
2. デバイス内に画像を保存するなら、Fileプラグインを使用
3. Ajaxを使いたいのであれば、FormDataオブジェクトを使って実装(http://blog.asial.co.jp/1271)

Answer (score 0):

オプションの`capture`が`accept`に入ってるけど、こうじゃないのかなぁ？と……

```
<input type="file" id="img" accept="image/*" capture="camera" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。書き方としては下記URLにあるように「capture」でいいようです。（初めて知った）
どの書き方でも出来ませんでしたが。。
http://walf443.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/02/04/005527

Comment: なるほど……。とりあえず上記記述で普通のブラウザでは動くのでAndroidのパーミッションの問題じゃないかと思います。ちなみにパーミッションは必要なプラグインを入れているようなので追加されているかと思いますが、反映されるのはビルド後のアプリのみです(カスタムデバッガーもビルドするから此方もパーミッションは有効かも)デバッガでは確認できないかと思います。確認方法はどうしていますか？

Comment: パーミッションはAndroidManifest.xmlに<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />を追記して、端末のアプリ情報で「写真と動画の撮影」が付いているのは確認しました。